# Using jq to return specific information in JSON object

Tags: json, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, jq, metrics

I wish to parse individual elements of inner JSON object to build / load in the database.

The following is the JSON object. How can I parse elements like id, name queue etc? I will iterate it in loop and work and build the insert query.

```
{
  "apps": {
    "app": [
      {
        "id": "application_1540378900448_18838",
        "user": "hive",
        "name": "insert overwrite tabl...summary_view_stg_etl(Stage-2)",
        "queue": "Data_Ingestion",
        "state": "FINISHED",
        "finalStatus": "SUCCEEDED",
        "progress": 100
       }, 
       {
        "id": "application_1540378900448_18833",
        "user": "hive",
        "name": "insert into SNOW_WORK...metric_definitions')(Stage-13)",
        "queue": "Data_Ingestion",
        "state": "FINISHED",
        "finalStatus": "SUCCEEDED",
        "progress": 100                                                         
        }
      ]
  }

  }
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be building a database query from the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its pretty simple just fetch elment which is having an array of values.

```js
 var JSONOBJ={
      "apps": {
        "app": [
          {
            "id": "application_1540378900448_18838",
            "user": "hive",
            "name": "insert overwrite tabl...summary_view_stg_etl(Stage-2)",
            "queue": "Data_Ingestion",
            "state": "FINISHED",
            "finalStatus": "SUCCEEDED",
            "progress": 100
           }, 
           {
            "id": "application_1540378900448_18833",
            "user": "hive",
            "name": "insert into SNOW_WORK...metric_definitions')(Stage-13)",
            "queue": "Data_Ingestion",
            "state": "FINISHED",
            "finalStatus": "SUCCEEDED",
            "progress": 100                                                         
            }
          ]
      }
    
    }
    
    JSONOBJ.apps.app.forEach(function(o){console.log(o.id);console.log(o.user);console.log(o.name);})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're better off converting the data to a format easily consumed by a database processor, like csv, then do something about it.

```
$ jq -r '(.apps.app[0] | keys_unsorted) as $k
    | $k, (.apps.app[] | [.[$k[]]])
    | @csv
' input.json
```